# Como pedir una pagina web para mostrarla

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, ecmascript-2015

Mi aplicación usa la autenticacion basada en tokens. En la pagina de login, mando los datos del usuario y la contraseña. debo recibir un token para establecerlo como **localStorage**. una vez que esta recibido y establecido. renderizar la pagina de bienvenida.

Este es mi código **Front end**

```
const formDataSignin = new FormData(formSignin);
event.preventDefault();
const header =
{
   method: 'post',
   body: formDataSignin
}

fetch('/signin', header)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res =>
 {
  localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
 });
```

Mi código **back End**

```
const newToken = token.createToken(answer);
res.render(user, {token, newToken})
return;
```

Comment: En las peticiones al servidor debes agregar un atributo al header `Authentication: Bearer [Token]` que es el mas común para JWT, aunque también existen otros métodos de identificación,

Comment: Si recibes el token será porque te has autenticado bien, el token te sirver para validar las siguientes peticiones. Cómo mostrar la pagina de bienvenida depende de cómo estes montando tu aplicación. Es un SPA? se genera el html en el server? son cosas que hay que saber.

Comment: Si. ya lo envió y lo recibo bien. y ya esta establecido en el localStorage. Pero la duda es como hacer para mostrar la pagina de bienvenida. Mas bien quiero realizar la accion de un formulario, reiniciar la pagina con otra pagina.

Comment: Y si se genera la pagina en el servidor. mediante una plantilla pug.